# YDSE - coherence of light from slits and width of slits

Tags: visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference, coherence

In Young's double slit experiment, 2 slits act as coherent sources. Why is coherence lost when the width of the slits is greater than half of the fringe width, i.e, if slit width is greater than the distance between a bright band and the nearest dark band? [image]

Here, if we put m=2 for position of second bright fringe, then put m=1 for position of first bright fringe, and then subtract both, we get λD/d , i.e. the fringe width or the distance between any 2 bright or dark bands. If we increase the width of the slits to greater than λD/2d , i.e half of the fringe width or the distance between any consecutive bright and dark bands, coherence of light is lost and interference pattern disappears. Why?

Comment: I just don’t understand the premise of the question. A diagram would likely help the question.

Comment: Roughly speaking, a slit is emitting light in all directions only if its width is small enough because of the diffraction happening when light goes trough the slit. If the slit is too wide, it will diffract less (in less wide angle). As you open the slits width, there will be less angle values for which the total light will be the interference of light coming from both slits, and you will loose the interference at wide angles.